# Is it possible to retroactively add "createdAt" key in each document of a mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, datecreated

I only recently thought it was a good idea to add **createdAt** as a default field in our **User** collection in mongoDB. Unfortunately, for all users that have signed up previously, this createdAt field is missing.

[image]

I feel like I am probably out of luck, but I wonder if perhaps the `createdAt` is either somehow encoded in the `_id`, or is available as metadata somewhere, anywhere. Is this possible?

As an aside, I have all of the email verification emails sent from our gmail account that are sent when a user signs up / gets added to this collection. It's a stretch, but maybe there's an automated way to extract all of those email send times, and use the `email` field to join those email send times onto our **User** collection.

Comment: You can use this method `objectIdValue.getTimestamp()` to get the document creation date - and i will be based upon the `_id` field value.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 12-byte [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value consists of:

- 4-byte **timestamp value**, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
- 5-byte **random value** generated once per process. This random value is unique to the machine and process.
- 3-byte **incrementing counter**, initialized to a random value.

For example:

`ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902a")`

`61e52e26` (hexadecimal) => `1642409510` (decimal) => `2022/1/17 08:51:50`

So you can use `_id` as `createdAt`